# Django filter in a View

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I'm just starting on Django, and currently stuck on a seemingly simple requirement/behaviour. I want a page rendered with a filtered set of entries based on the class's ForeignKey, and called from a rendered view of that other class.

A simplified version of my model.py is:

```
from django.db import models

class BookDay(models.Model):
    bookdate = models.DateField()
    bookevent = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class BookTime(models.Model):
    booktime = models.TimeField()
    bookdate = models.ForeignKey(BookDay, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

My view.py reads:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import generic

from .models import BookDay, BookTime

class DayView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'booking/days.html'
    context_object_name = 'bookdate_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
     return BookDay.objects.order_by('bookdate')

class TimeView(generic.ListView):
    model = BookDay 
    template_name = 'booking/booktimes.html'
    context_object_name = 'booktimes_list'
    def get_queryset(self):
     return BookTime.objects.filter(bookdate=bookday_id).order_by('booktime')
```

My urls.py contains:

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views

    app_name = 'booking'
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.DayView.as_view(), name='bookdays'),
        path('<int:pk>/', views.TimeView.as_view(), name='booktimes'),
    ]
```

The referenced days.html renders a set of links per this fragment:

```
{% for entry in bookdate_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'booking:teetimes' entry.id %}">{{ entry.bookevent }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

On clicking any of the resulting links, the failure manifests as `name 'bookday_id' is not defined`.

I can put a fixed integer in place of `bookday_id` in views.py above, and it works fine (for that ForeignKey only, obviously). Also, I've played around with the filter() parameter name, the relevant url, and the html extensively to no avail.

How should I parameterise this to take the clicked link and filter the BookTimes entries correctly? Should I use Django-filter for this, or can it be done natively in Django?

Answer (score 7):

Well like the error specifies, there is no `bookday_id` variable. If I understand it correctly, you are interested in the `pk` parameter of the URL. You can access these *positional* and *named* parameter in the `self.args` and `self.kwargs` of the `View` objects, so you can rewrite it to:

```
class TimeView(generic.ListView):
    model = BookDay 
    template_name = 'booking/booktimes.html'
    context_object_name = 'booktimes_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return BookTime.objects.filter(bookdate_id=self.kwargs['pk']).order_by('booktime')
```

Since the `pk` is an `int`, we thus filter on the `bookdate_id` (which is an integer here).

I would however advice to rename your `bookdate` foreignkey to `bookday` (the name of the model it refers to), since now it creates some confusion with the `bookdate` field of the `BookDay` model.

Comment: Tks for that fast response. Just implemented your fix and it works a dream. I'll go back to my model defn to do that naming change you advised. Tks again.